# Load array of array in ng-option

Tags: angularjs

I have the following array in Javascript:

```
[["30-11-2013", "November 2013"], ["01-11-2013", "November 2013"], ["30-11-2012", "November 2012"]]
```

It should populate an ng-option:

```
"ng-options" => "o as o for o in options", "value" => "o"
```

That produces this option:

```
<option value="1">01-11-2013,November 2013</option>
```

But I need

```
<option value="01-11-2013">November 2013</option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just index it:

```
<select ng-model="selectedModel" ng-options="o[0] as o[1] for o in options"></select>
```

Note that the `select` will be written with values of 0, 1, 2, 3, etc.  This is OK, because Angular will put the correct value in `ng-model` when it is selected (you can't put an object in a value location, so it maps it for you).

Also, you probably (usually) don't want to set `value`.  Just use `ng-model` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use angular filters

"o as o for o in options | date:'MMMM yyyy"

more details can be found here

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:date

Comment: He doesn't have a date object, but a length-two array of strings.